# rabbitmq basic.ack , on a different channel object

Tags: java, tomcat, rabbitmq, mq

here is the implementation I have

Consume:

```
GetResponse resp = channel.basicGet(qName, false);
```

Acknowledge:

```
channel.basicAck(dTag, false);
```

or

```
channel.basicNack(dTag, false,true);
```

The problem I am facing that is, if I create different channel objects, the acknowledge is not happening.
And I can only implement that if I am doing both ( consume, acknowledge ) from same jvm( tomcat or any other app server ).

so if my application is running in a clustered mode( multiple application server ) , I am in trouble .

Can anyone please help me how can I acknowledge from a different machine the message was consumed, i.e. using a different channelobject .

Thanks !!

Comment: Acking must happen on the same channel. You can't ack a message from another machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone please help me how can I acknowledge from a different machine the message was consumed, i.e. using a different channelobject .

you can't.

acknowledgement must happen on the same channel.

Comment: First of all Thanks ton, for your help. I was kinda beating around the bush ...
I found your site on Rabbit, and found you are quite an expert on this. Can I ask you a question on Rabbit?


Here it is 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610842/rabbitmq-limitation-clustering

Comment: i commented on an existing answer in your other question. your setup sounds like it's appropriate, already