# RabbitMq limitations and clustering

Tags: tomcat, redis, rabbitmq, amazon-elb

Our application is currently serving around 1500 transactions per second. We have Rabbit as a queue. But we store only the transaction ID in Rabbit, the actual message which is 1-5 mb in size, we are storing in Redis (an in-memory database). My question is, can we remove Redis altogether, and just use Rabbit - will it sustain?

One more thing: can we increase the number of Rabbit instances horizontally, as we expect load will scale up pretty fast (we have already tested an master master replication successfully).

Comment: You shouldn't be storing anything in RabbitMQ, it's not a database.

Answer (score 3):

In general this sounds like not a good idea to me. Rabbit is a messaging system, not a database.

The messages have to be stored in Rabbit somewhere. If some Rabbit instance gets down, you'll lose your messages. If you use persistence, the situation will be even worse:

Clustered Rabbit should synchronize each and every message, so restarting any Rabbit node that has a replicated node will take ages.

In fact, I believe now you have the best solution :)

Comment: i would also add that a 1MB message is going to be very slow moving through RabbitMQ, and it slows down even more when you head out to 5MB. keep your messages small so they can route and be consumed very fast. your current setup sounds like the correct setup.